# Rails search method

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have tried using sql to write a simple search method, I have so far written this;

```
User.where("username LIKE '#{input}'")
```

the input variable is 'adam', however I don't want to find the username's that are equal to 'adam' I want to find usernames that include 'adam' or include the letter 'a' etc.... I was wondering how I would go about doing that? I am not very familiar with sql queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
User.where("username LIKE '%#{input}%'") 
     OR
User.where("username like ?","%name%")
```

Comment: That only finds the username equal to the input, is it possible to find a user where their username includes say the letter 'ada' and find's the users that have the letters 'ada' in the username.

Comment: @AdamParker with '%' chars it will search exactly as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you create method then go to model page & then follow this structure like below:

```
 def self.username(username)
   if username
     where("username LIKE ?", "%#{username}%")
   else
     all
  end
 end
```

Or create only controller like below:

```
User.where(["username LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:username]}%"])
```

I think will help you